# How can I change the div position while mouse over?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have used the below code for showing a popup along with change position while hovering.  My problem is that the hover part is not set to the old position after mouse leave.

How can I close that bio-info popup?

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="ch-grid">
  <li>
<div class="bioinfo">
 <h2>tooltips</h2>
/div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bioinfo {
    display: none;
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(108,108,108, 0.5) 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    right: -150px;
    z-index: 100;
/*    background: #eeeded; f6f6f6*/
    background: rgba(246,246,246, 0.8);
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 15px 3px 3px 3px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(function() {
        //$('.ch-item').click(function() {

            //alert('ddl');
            //$(this).css({position: 'relative', left: -200});
            $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
            $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
}, function() {
    $($(this).data('.bioinfo')).hide();
});
```

How can I reset the position after mouse leave?

I have used

```
$(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
```

for moving the div when hovering.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little better?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a messy way to do it. I would rather create a class that has the altered CSS properties, and then toggle that class on and off as you hover in and out of it. It would also shorten the code needed for the hover function, too.

Comment: He is already defining the handlerOut event, just not resetting the margin. If resetting the right margin, it should be 0, not -150, but moreover I agree the best method would be to toggle a css class and define all the styles/states in the css.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @thebiffboff. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for your code would be to reset the right margin on the mouseout event:

```
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).css({ marginRight: 0});
    $(this).children('.bioinfo')).hide();
});
```

However, you aren't doing anything here that couldn't be done with pure CSS. Remove the jQuery and add this CSS to achieve the same result:

```
.ch-grid > li:hover{ position: relative; right: 120px; }
.ch-grid > li:hover .bioinfo{ display: block; }
```

As requested in your comment below, here is how to do it with animation. 1500 is the animation length in milliseconds, alter these to tweak the animation to how you'd like it.

```
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120}, 1500);
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({marginRight: 0}, 1500);
    $(this).children('.bioinfo')).hide();
});
```

Comment: its really amazing. how to move right side very slowly? I have tried following code but not use.
$('.ch-grid > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({position: 'relative', marginRight: 120});
    $(this).children('.bioinfo').show('slow').css({display: 'inline-block'});}, function() {
    $(this).css({ marginRight: 0});
    $(this).children('.bioinfo')).hide();
});